# Вложенный цикл каждый раз возвращает все свойства всех объектов в массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, таблицы

Всем привет!

Хочу написать простую вещь - что бы когда пользователь отправлял форму, все значения из инпутов выводились на странице в таблице. Для этого из инпутов я собираю объект и кладу его в массив. После этого прохожусь циклом по массиву, что бы получить все элементы массива (в моем случае это объекты), и для каждого объекта прохожусь следующим циклом по всем его свойствам. И где то здесь происходит что то непонятное для меня. Каждый раз после того как запускается этот цикл в цикле, он возвращает все элементы с первого по последний. Т.е. это выглядит так:

- Цикл 1: 1
- Цикл 2: 1,2
- Цикл 2: 1,2,3
- ...

Из-за этого ломается вся моя таблица, т.к. код добавляет все эти значения в одну строку, а не в следующую строку.

Вот мой код:

```
const modelElem = document.getElementById('model-input');
const priceElem = document.getElementById('price-input');
const benefitElem = document.getElementById('benefit-input');
const calcBtnElem = document.getElementById('calc-btn');
let cars = [];
let carId = 0;

// Сборка таблицы из массива
function createDataTable() {
    let dataTable = document.getElementById('data-table');
    let tBody = document.getElementById('tbody');
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    let cell = document.createElement("td");

    for (let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
        // console.log(cars[i].model);
        for (let key in cars[i]) {
            let cell = document.createElement("td");
            cell.innerHTML = cars[i][key];
            // console.log(key + " " + cars[i][key]);
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
        tBody.appendChild(row);
    }
}

// Создание объекта модели
function CarData(model, price, benefit) {
    carId++;
    let halfPrice = String(half(price));

    if (benefit === "") {
        benefit = "–"
        benefitPrice = price;
    } else {
        benefitPrice = String(price - benefit);
    }
    // Порядок создания значений важен для таблицы на фронте!
    this.carId = carId;
    this.model = model;
    this.price = price;
    this.halfPrice = halfPrice;
    this.benefit = benefit;
    this.benefitPrice = benefitPrice;
}

// Получаем половину числа
function half(number) {
    return number / 2;
}

// Функция проверки инпутов и оповещения
function checkRequired() {
    let fieldRequerdElem = document.querySelectorAll('.field-alert');

    if (modelElem.value == "" && priceElem.value == "") {
        alert('Вы не заполнили поле ' + 'Model' + ' и ' + 'Price');
    } else if (modelElem.value == "") {
        alert('Вы не заполнили поле ' + 'Model');
    } else if (priceElem.value == "") {
        alert('Вы не заполнили поле ' + 'Price');
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

// Отправляем форму
calcBtnElem.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault(); // Отменяем стандартное поведение кнопки

    // Проверка на заполненность инпутов
    if (checkRequired()) {
        let model = modelElem.value.trim();
        let price = priceElem.value.trim();
        let benefit = benefitElem.value.trim();
        let car = new CarData(model, price, benefit); // Создаем объект
        cars.push(car); // Добавляем Объект в массив
        createDataTable();
        document.querySelector('form').reset(); // Чистим форму после
    }
});
```

А вот он же в песочнице, что бы можно было воспроизвести ошибку: https://jsfiddle.net/yastaraus/8g52ma0v/16/.
Нужно отправить несколько раз форму что бы увидеть в чем проблема.

Можете пожалуйста объяснить, что я упускаю и почему не выходит? Нужно что бы при каждом нажатии кнопки добавлялась новая строка со свежими данными. Может быть есть другой, более простой способ сделать то, что я хочу? С радостью почитаю любые адекватные советы. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`let row = document.createElement("tr");` — создается один раз, вне цикла, а все `td` добавляются туда. На каждой итерации нужно создавать новую `tr`.

И нужно перед созданием таблицы стирать всё, что было до, чтобы все предыдущие строки повторно не добавлялись после каждого клика.

Добавил две строчки (и убрал объявление `cell` вне цикла, тоже не нужен):

```js
const modelElem = document.getElementById('model-input');
const priceElem = document.getElementById('price-input');
const benefitElem = document.getElementById('benefit-input');
const calcBtnElem = document.getElementById('calc-btn');

let carId = 0;

let cars = [
  new CarData(1, 1, 1),
  new CarData(2, 2, 2),
  new CarData(3, 3, 3),
];   // ← (*!) удобно заранее хранить несколько объектов,
     // чтобы каждый раз руками их не вводить для тестов.

createDataTable();

function createDataTable() {
  let dataTable = document.getElementById('data-table');
  let tBody = document.getElementById('tbody');

  tbody.innerHTML = ""; // <---

  for (let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    let row = document.createElement("tr"); // <---

    for (let key in cars[i]) {
      let cell = document.createElement("td");

      cell.innerHTML = cars[i][key];
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    tBody.appendChild(row);
  }
}

// Создание объекта модели
function CarData(model, price, benefit) {
  carId++;
  let halfPrice = String(half(price));

  if (benefit === "") {
    benefit = "–"
    benefitPrice = price;
  } else {
    benefitPrice = String(price - benefit);
  }
  // Порядок создания значений важен для таблицы на фронте!
  this.carId = carId;
  this.model = model;
  this.price = price;
  this.halfPrice = halfPrice;
  this.benefit = benefit;
  this.benefitPrice = benefitPrice;
}

// Получаем половину числа
function half(number) {
  return number / 2;
}

// Функция проверки инпутов и оповещения
function checkRequired() {
  let fieldRequerdElem = document.querySelectorAll('.field-alert');

  if (modelElem.value == "" && priceElem.value == "") {
    alert('Вы не заполнили поле ' + 'Model' + ' и ' + 'Price');
  } else if (modelElem.value == "") {
    alert('Вы не заполнили поле ' + 'Model');
  } else if (priceElem.value == "") {
    alert('Вы не заполнили поле ' + 'Price');
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

calcBtnElem.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault(); // Отменяем стандартное поведение кнопки

  // Проверка на заполненность инпутов
  if (checkRequired()) {
    let model = modelElem.value.trim();
    let price = priceElem.value.trim();
    let benefit = benefitElem.value.trim();
    let car = new CarData(model, price, benefit); // Создаем объект
    cars.push(car); // Добавляем Объект в массив
    createDataTable();
    document.querySelector('form').reset(); // Чистим форму после
  }
});
```

```html
<main class="main-grid">
  <!-- Input Section -->
  <section class="lh-section lh-section__dark form-section">
    <header>
      <h2 class="lh-h2-title">Input</h2>
    </header>
    <form class="addmodel-form" autocomplete="off">
      <div class="input-block">
        <label for="model-input">Model</label>
        <input id="model-input" class="model-input" type="text" name="model" required>
      </div>
      <div class="input-block">
        <label for="price-input">Price</label>
        <input id="price-input" class="price-input" type="number" name="price" required>
      </div>
      <div class="input-block">
        <label for="benefit-input">Benefit</label>
        <input id="benefit-input" class="benefit-input" type="number" name="benefit">
      </div>
      <div class="btn-collection">
        <button id="calc-btn" class="btn btn-white calc-btn">Add</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </section>

  <!-- Output Section -->
  <section class="lh-section lh-section__light data-section">
    <header>
      <h2 class="lh-h2-title">Output</h2>
    </header>
    <div class="table-container">
      <table id="data-table" class="data-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col" width="2%">Id</th>
            <th scope="col" width="18%">Model</th>
            <th scope="col" width="18%">Price</th>
            <th scope="col" width="16%">Half price</th>
            <th scope="col" width="14%">Benefit</th>
            <th scope="col" width="18%">Price w/ benefit</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="tbody" id="tbody">
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

  </section>
</main>
```

Вместо пересоздания таблицы целиком, можно было бы сделать какую-нибудь функцию `insert(car)`, которая берет один объект машины и добавляет одну строку в таблицу. И при каждом клике передать туда последний созданный объект.